# How do I insert a string into an empty XML?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a string that is in `XML` format my string is:

```
<Commits>
    <Repository></Repository>
    <Commit>
        <Author>rohitsarkar1000@gmail.com</Author>
        <Commit_Date>2021-06-04 10:55:27 +0530</Commit_Date>
        <Message_Body>Multiple files</Message_Body>
        <PreviousCommit_Id></PreviousCommit_Id> 
        <Commit_Id>8ca4c0612ed785ba200a77763dca68c473f4af17</Commit_Id>
        <Branch_Name>HEAD -> master, origin/master</Branch_Name>
        <Files_List></Files_List>
    </Commit>
</Commits>
```

I want to insert this string into an `XML` file that I have already created. How can I do that?

I have another scenario

I have string variable string gitEventXml it contains

```
<Commits>
    <Repository></Repository>
    <Commit>
        <Author>rohitsarkar1000@gmail.com</Author>
        <Commit_Date>2021-06-04 10:55:27 +0530</Commit_Date>
        <Message_Body>Multiple files</Message_Body>
        <PreviousCommit_Id></PreviousCommit_Id>
        <Commit_Id>8ca4c0612ed785ba200a77763dca68c473f4af17</Commit_Id>
        <Branch_Name>HEAD -> master, origin/master</Branch_Name>
        <Files_List></Files_List>
    </Commit>
</Commits>
```

This as string. In the Repository tag I want to insert .git. The string will look like

```
<Commits><Repository>.git</Repository>....
```

How can I achieve it? Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: [File.WriteAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will be more efficient for the second scenario.

```
XElement eventXml = XElement.Parse(gitEventXml);
string repo = ".git";
XElement tagXmlToInsert = XElement.Parse($"<Repository>{repo}</Repository>");
XElement mainElement = eventXml.Descendants("Commit").FirstOrDefault();
XElement mainElement.AddBeforeSelf(tagXmlToInsert);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution of first problem:

```
string gitEventXml = @"<Commits><Repository></Repository><Commit><Author>rohitsarkar1000@gmail.com</Author><Commit_Date>2021-06-04 10:55:27 +0530</Commit_Date><Message_Body>Multiple files</Message_Body><PriviousCommit_Id></PriviousCommit_Id><Commit_Id>8ca4c0612ed785ba200a77763dca68c473f4af17</Commit_Id><Branch_Name>HEAD -> master, origin/master</Branch_Name><Files_List></Files_List></Commit></Commits>";
File.WriteAllText("D:/MyXmlFile.xml", gitEventXml);
```

Solution for second:

```
string insertValue = ".git";
string gitEventXml = $"<Commits><Repository>{insertValue}</Repository><Commit><Author>rohitsarkar1000@gmail.com</Author><Commit_Date>2021-06-04 10:55:27 +0530</Commit_Date><Message_Body>Multiple files</Message_Body><PriviousCommit_Id></PriviousCommit_Id><Commit_Id>8ca4c0612ed785ba200a77763dca68c473f4af17</Commit_Id><Branch_Name>HEAD -> master, origin/master</Branch_Name><Files_List></Files_List></Commit></Commits>";
File.WriteAllText("D:/MyXmlFile.xml", gitEventXml);
```

Another dynamic way to insert value:

```
string insertValue = ".git";
string gitEventXml = $"<Commits><Repository></Repository><Commit><Author>rohitsarkar1000@gmail.com</Author><Commit_Date>2021-06-04 10:55:27 +0530</Commit_Date><Message_Body>Multiple files</Message_Body><PriviousCommit_Id></PriviousCommit_Id><Commit_Id>8ca4c0612ed785ba200a77763dca68c473f4af17</Commit_Id><Branch_Name>HEAD -> master, origin/master</Branch_Name><Files_List></Files_List></Commit></Commits>";
if (gitEventXml.Contains("<Repository>"))
{
    string[] parts = gitEventXml.Split("<Repository>");
    gitEventXml = $"{parts[0]}<Repository>{insertValue}{parts[1]}";
}
File.WriteAllText("D:/MyXmlFile.xml", gitEventXml);
```

Comment: My second scenario is  string gitEventXml = <Commits><Repository></Repository><Commit><Author>rohitsarkar1000@gmail.com</Author><Commit_Date>2021-06-04 10:55:27 +0530</Commit_Date><Message_Body>Multiple files</Message_Body><PriviousCommit_Id></PriviousCommit_Id><Commit_Id>8ca4c0612ed785ba200a77763dca68c473f4af17</Commit_Id><Branch_Name>HEAD -> master, origin/master</Branch_Name><Files_List></Files_List></Commit></Commits>

Here in this string there is <Repository></Repository> I want to insert .git here 

I am not asking about git tags btw thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I want to achieve <Repository>.git</Repository> this

Comment: I have updated the code, you can insert any dynamic string value like the code shown above. will that solved your problem?

Comment: @RohitSarkar do you want further help or your problem soled? if solved you can mark and close this else i can try to help further.

Comment: Actually I am getting the string from git command response after getting the string in this format how I am able to go and add {insertValue} to the string . thats my actual problem If i am able to add {insertValue} to the string my problem will be solved

Comment: @RohitSarkar - try the last appened code snippet, it will work as you expected. Checks and validation you can decide based on your code flow, i have just created sample.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233463/discussion-between-pashyant-srivastava-and-rohit-sarkar).

Comment: I would strongly recommend against using straight string operations for this. They won't cover characters that need escaping, etc. It would be much better to use an XML API to parse the existing XML, find the right element, set the text value, and then write out the new XML.

Comment: @JonSkeet actually I have a response from git command that comes as an string in XML format. Can you suggest some better solution then Pashyant it would be very helpful. Btw  his code is working fine for me.

Comment: @PashyantSrivastava Thanks buddy for you help and effort.

Comment: @RohitSarkar: I've already given the outline of it. I'd suggest using LINQ to XML for this - if you haven't used that before, I'd suggest starting with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/linq-xml-overview